# How to access a different drive in cmd with 'no access'

Tags: windows, cmd.exe

I have an Alienware R4 and I have lost my keyboard and mouse drivers. The only way I could get them back is to launch System Restore. However, Windows Update comes along and restarts my computer and I have to start the System Restore again to get my drivers back. I have tried using a different keyboard/mouse with no luck.

I believe the Microsoft USB drivers got deleted during a power outage or a Windows Update. Now I want to use the disk that came with the computer to copy the drivers from a USB thumb drive or CD that I have copied the drivers on to `\windows\system32\drivers`. However, when I get there, I have no access to this drive or I get some other error.  I've used `E:> copy *.sys C:\windows\system32\drivers` and get no path found or no access on different occasions. I have been with this for weeks now and need some help please.

Comment: To be simple, do you mean you want to copy the drive from some other location to `C:\windows\system32\drivers `?